# Java, change char to string

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class PickTwoCards {

    final static int CardNumbers = 13;
    final static char[] Types = {'c','h','d','s'};

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Card CardOne = ChooseCard();
        System.out.println("*****Welcome to the House of Cards*****");
        System.out.println("My card is the "+CardOne.GetNumber()+" of "+CardOne.GetType());
    
        Card CardTwo = ChooseCard();
        System.out.println("My card is the "+CardTwo.GetNumber()+" of "+CardTwo.GetType());
    }

    public static Card ChooseCard(){
        Card card = new Card();
        card.SetType(RandomType());
        card.SetNumber(RandomNumber());
        return card;
    }

    public static char RandomType(){
        int RandomTypeKeep = new Random().nextInt(Types.length);
        char RandomType = Types[RandomTypeKeep];
        return RandomType;
    }

    public static int RandomNumber(){
        int RandomCardNumber = ((int)(Math.random()*100)%CardNumbers+1);
        return RandomCardNumber;
    }
}
```

```
public class Card {

    private static char type;
    private static int number;

    public static char GetType() {
        return type;
    }

    public static void SetType(char type) {
        Card.type = type;
    }

    public static int GetNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public static void SetNumber(int number) {
        Card.number = number;
    }
}
```

The result should be:

```
*****Welcome to the House of Cards*****.
My card is the 3 of Spade.
My card is the 2 of Diamond.
```

I do not know how to make my result value as a string like "Diamond", not a "d".

Comment: Add a `getTypeDescription` method which converts the type to a human readable value.  Oh, and get rid of `static`, otherwise all your cards will have the same value

Comment: Fix your formatting for code: Either indent by four spaces, or wrap in a pair of triple back-ticks.

Answer (score 2):

Drop `static`.  This is not how it should be used and isn't going to help you in this situation.  As it is, each `Card` would have the same value, no matter how you changed it.

You could add a `description` method, to convert the `char` to human readable `String`, for example

```
public class Card {

    private char type;
    private int number;

    public char getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(char type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    
    public String getTypeDescription() {
        switch (getType()) {
            case 'c': return "Clubs";
            case 'h': return "Hearts";
            case 'd': return "Dimonds";
            case 's': return "Spads";
        }
        
        return "---";
    }
}
```

> Why not just override `toString`

.  IMHO people jump on `toString` way too early and misuse it.  Now ask yourself, what happens if you also want to show the `suit` and `number` at different points (and not all the time)?  You can't modify `toString` to do this, and you've constrained its use to a single use case.  So, instead, we provide the means for the developer to make better decisions about what they want, instead of forcing it on them.

Personally, `toString` is really, really useful for debugging.

Now, if you really wanted to do something "fancy", you could create a `Suit` `enum` with a customised `toString` method...

```
enum Suit {
    CLUBS {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Clubs";
        }
    },
    HEARTS {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Hearts";
        }
    },
    DIAMONDS {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Diamonds";
        }
    }, SPADES {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Spades";
        }
    };
}
```

Then just update the `Card` class to support it...

```
public class Card {

    private Suit type;
    private int number;

    public Suit getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Suit type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

And then you can just use it something like ...

```
Card card = new Card();
card.setType(Suit.CLUBS);

System.out.println(card.getType());
```

> But now you're overriding `toString`, I'm confused

Yes, I don't blame you.  For every rule, there is an exception

If you have a look at the JavaDocs for [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name()) it actually states:

> **Most programmers should use the toString() method in preference to this one, as the toString method may return a more user-friendly name**

In this particular case, you're very unlikely going to want to change what is returned from `toString`.  If you'd prefer to return a emoji instead, then I'd actually supply that via a seperate method, but that's me